# how noscript tag treated in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, noscript

I can't see any explanation about this anywhere.

I simply want to know *what* browsers generate with the data inside the `noscript` tag, *if* the JS is enabled.

**For example:**

According to HTML5 specs, it is allowed to use `noscript` tag inside `head` tag.

```
<head>
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="basic.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</noscript>
</head>
```

The reason I'm asking this question is that I'm afraid some browsers may treat the `noscript` tag as something as text(if JS is enabled), and as a result it will load/add unnecessarily data.

So, how browsers actually treat the `noscript` tag?

Thanks.

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you provide a quote where it is answers my question?

Comment: @JaromandaX but It doesn't answer __what__ browser generate with the data inside the `noscript` tag

Comment: oh, you want to know what happens with the content of `<noscript>` when JS is enabled - sorry, I totally misread your question - let me remove my cruft

Comment: `The noscript element represents nothing if scripting is enabled, and represents its children if scripting is disabled.` - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element - that doesn't say what individual browsers ACTUALLY DO, though, but my previously linked MDN page makes no mention of any deviation to this standard

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest if internet search hasn't yielded the definitive answer you're looking for is to test as many browsers as you have access to (there are virtual ones online you can use to test as well)

Comment: @JaromandaX Really odd. So, basically they _delete_ the inside data of `noscript` if JS is enabled? Or how could "nothing" be interpreted otherwise. Thank you, Jaromanda

Comment: It will go insane, because not only browsers I would need to test, but also the version of each. This could take days :)

Comment: seriously, I think you need to check current versions only (which is a minefield with Internet Explorer - perhaps IE11/9/7) it's such an old spec, I really don't think you have anything to worry about

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok then, thanks for helping me out pal

Answer (score 1):

> The HTML  Element defines a section of html to be inserted
>   if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is
>   currently turned off in the browser. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Also

> The noscript element represents nothing if scripting is enabled, and
>   represents its children if scripting is disabled. It is used to
>   present different markup to user agents that support scripting and
>   those that don't support scripting, by affecting how the document is
>   parsed. [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element).

`noscript` tag is well supported among browsers and as far I know there is no deviation from standard specification.

By the way if you really need make sure of its behavior across different browser you can use a Web-Based Browser Testing tools as https://www.browserstack.com which would speed up your testing process.

Comment: the question is __what__ become with the `noscript` tag's content(what it generates) if the JS enabled.

Comment: @virosimus thanks for commenting. I have updated my answer with links to w3 sources.

Comment: Hm... I can't use `@Gibbok` with your nickname for some reason :) Anyway, I appreciate your help, but this adds nothing to Jaromanda X's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, remember that the HTML5 spec describes two syntaxes, the (regular) HTML one when the page is served as `text/html` and the XHTML one when the page is served as `application/xhtml+xml`. The browser does different things depending on which syntax is used.

I expect that what you are interested in is the `text/html` syntax, so for that, the spec describes what happens in [section 8 - The HTML syntax](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#syntax).

We then need to follow the tree construction stage of the parser algorithm and for your example, where the `<noscript>` element is in the head section, look under [The "in head" insertion mode](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-in-head-insertion-mode). Searching down from there you will find `A start tag whose tag name is "noscript, if the scripting flag is enabled` which links to the [generic raw text element parsing algorithm.](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#generic-raw-text-element-parsing-algorithm).

This puts the tokenizer in the [RAWTEXT state](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#rawtext-state) which means that all characters are just passed though until the `</noscript>` tag is found (i.e. entity references are not resolved) and the insertion mode is switched the [The "text" insertion mode](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-text-insertion-mode).

This just adds each character to a text node until the `</noscript>` tag is found when the insertion mode switches back to the previous mode e.g. the "in head" insertion mode and the parsing of the `<noscript>` element has then been completed.

The result for your example is that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="basic.css" type="text/css" media="all" />` will be the uninterpreted contents of a text node as the sole child of the `<noscript>` element.